# Starting a process inside controller

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Consider such module:

```
defmodule Sampple do
  def start(nick, password, state \\ %State{}) do
    {:ok, client} = ExIrc.start_client!
    GenServer.start(__MODULE__,
      [%{state | client: client,
         nick: nick,
         pass: password
        }]
    )
  end
  def enter(nick, token) do
    Logger.debug "Sending message"
    start(nick, token)
  end
  #another irrelevant callbacks
  def handle_info({:joined, _}, state) do
    ExIrc.Client.msg(state.client,
      :privmsg,
      state.channel,
      "!enter")
    {:stop, :normal, state}
  end
end
```

Such GenServer is being instantiated like this in Phoenix Copntroller:

```
defmodule Cgas.Controller do
  use Cgas.Web, :controller
  require Logger
  def enter(conn, _args) do
    Logger.debug inspect(get_session(conn, :login))
    %{"login" => login,
      "token" => token } = get_session(conn, :login)
    {:ok, pid} = Sample.enter(login, token)
    Logger.debug inspect(pid)
    json conn, %{"success" => "true "}
  end
end
```

If `enter` is called from repl or non controller process there is no problem, although when it's called from inside controller action the process is alive but doesn't do anything. This sample module is used as ExIRC handler.

Comment: Which enter is called from repl?

Comment: And how do you verify if the process is alive?

Comment: I check whether process is alive by `Process.alive?`. I've called it from repl and `enter` works.

Comment: Which enter. There are two of them

Comment: The `enter` from sample which `start`s a process.

Comment: Is `Cgas.GiveAwayEnterer` and `Sampple` supposed to be the same module or is there a missing code in here?

Comment: Yes... Forgot to change it while reformating..

Answer (score 0):

**Cause**

First of all controllers are all separate processes. Which means that when a user makes a request the process starts and when he gets a response the process dies.
By starting a process with a start_link you create a bi-directional link which makes the death event propagate to other linked processes. Which means if you've got connection like:

```
Cgas.Controller <----> Sample
```

It mean that if either `Sample` or `Cgas.Controller` die, both of them will. And according to inner system of how controllers works it mean that `Sample` will live as long as the clients connection to the server will (which is usually 1-100ms)

That might be the reason why you notice it "not doing anything" because it just didn't have enough time in its life (poor thing)

**Solution**

First thing you could do is simply start the process with `start/2` instead of `start_link/2` However it'll create a single process for each request made to the server which will most likely end up as an army of zombie processes.

If you really insist on doing it so you can just give it a time to live. Something like a register of processes and:
 `# if client didn't make any new request in X seconds commit suicide 
:erlang.exit self, :'die!'`

But generally it's agains the fire and forget rule of web frameworks, and it'd be much better to use a real time connection like WebSockets for that and make the process live as long as the connection lives.

Comment: `start` has same effect